# Pool filler service with minimum and maximum threshold setting

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I'd like to make application which has a pool (unlimited) of some objects. When the pool's size reach some minimum threshold I want to start my pool filler service and produce a certain number of new objects (till reaching of maximum threshold).

This is slightly modified version of `producer-consumer` problem, but somehow I got stuck. As it's easy to create `BlockingQueue` with limited size and keeping it filled, I have no idea how to solve my problem.

I tried using `ReentrantLock` and it's `Condition` objects, but `Condition#signal()` method requires me to be inside lock, which is totally unnecessary in my case.

In my opinion the best solution would be something like `CountDownLatch`. Consumers would decrease counter and eventually trigger pool filler service. What is wrong here is `CountDownLatch`'s unability to restart itself.

Any ideas?

*in other words*: I have a buch of consumer threads and one which is a producer. Producer should wait until minimum threshold is reached, produce some objects, and then wait again.

Comment: Can't the producer recreate the CountDownLatch once it comes alive? So that consumers can now decrement the new CountDownLatch?

Comment: It possibly could, but resulting code would smell bad :) That's why I am asking for better solution.

Comment: You can extend ArrayBlockingQueue to your own custom queue and override appropriate methods in it. All the PUT'ting methods can reset the CountDownLatch and all the GETting methods can decrement the CountDownLatch. Consumers and Producers are totally insulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Semaphore` can act as a barrier for the producer and is re-usable. When the `Semaphore` is combined with an `AtomicBoolean`, the producer can work without affecting the consumers. It does require the pool to handle the filling logic.

In the implementation below the producer immediately starts filling the pool and then waits for the pool to reach its minimum size.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

// http://stackoverflow.com/q/32358084/3080094
public class RandomWell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            final FilledPool<Integer> pool = new FilledPool<Integer>(100, 1000);
            final CountDownLatch syncStart = new CountDownLatch(3);

            Thread consumer = new Thread() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    // just to do something, keep track of amount of positive ints from pool
                    int positiveInt = 0;
                    int totalInts = 0;
                    try {
                        syncStart.countDown();
                        syncStart.await();
                        for(;;) {
                            int i = pool.take();
                            if (i > 0) {
                                positiveInt++;
                            }
                            totalInts++;
                            Thread.yield();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Consumer stopped: " + positiveInt + " / " + (totalInts - positiveInt));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            consumer.start();

            Thread producer = new Thread() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    try {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        syncStart.countDown();
                        syncStart.await();
                        for(;;) {
                            int fillTotal = 0;
                            while (!pool.isMinFilled()) {
                                int fill = pool.getFillSize();
                                for (int i = 0; i < fill; i++) {
                                    pool.offer(r.nextInt());
                                }
                                fillTotal += fill;
                                // System.out.println("Pool size: " + pool.sizeFast());
                            }
                            System.out.println("Filled " + fillTotal);
                            pool.awaitNewFilling();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Producer stopped.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            producer.start();
            syncStart.countDown();
            syncStart.await();

            Thread.sleep(100);

            producer.interrupt();
            consumer.interrupt();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class FilledPool<E> {

        private final LinkedBlockingQueue<E> pool;
        private final int minSize;
        private final int maxSize;
        private final Semaphore needFilling = new Semaphore(0);

        // producer starts filling initially
        private final AtomicBoolean filling = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        public FilledPool(int minSize, int maxSize) {
            super();
            this.minSize = minSize;
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
            pool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<E>();
        }

        public E take() throws InterruptedException {

            triggerFilling();
            E e = pool.take();
            return e;
        }

        private void triggerFilling() {

            if (!isFilling() && !isMinFilled() && filling.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                needFilling.release();
                System.out.println("Filling triggered.");
            }
        }

        public void offer(E e) { pool.offer(e); }

        public void awaitNewFilling() throws InterruptedException {

            // must check on minimum in case consumers outpace producer
            if (isMinFilled()) {
                filling.set(false);
                needFilling.acquire();
            }
        }

        public int size() { return pool.size(); }
        public boolean isMinFilled() { return minSize < size(); }
        public int getFillSize() { return maxSize - size(); } 
        public boolean isFilling() { return filling.get(); }
    }
}
```

Update: I also managed to get it working using a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of a `LinkedBlockingQueue` which about doubles the throughput but at the same time doubles the complexity of the code.

Comment: That's right, `Semaphore` is elegant solution here. The only thing that is annoying me in this particular case is unability to `aquireAll` :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.  It uses a [ReentrantLock.tryLock()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()) to ensure that only a single thread is ever filling, and only when you're below a threshold.

The sample code posted here will run for 30 seconds and then stop.

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Filler {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

        final LinkedBlockingDeque<Object> linkedBlockingDeque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        final Lock fillLock = new ReentrantLock();
        final AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new Worker(linkedBlockingDeque, fillLock, stop));
        }

        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
        stop.set(true);
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

}

class Worker implements Runnable {

    private final LinkedBlockingDeque<Object> linkedBlockingDeque;
    private final Lock fillLock;
    private final AtomicBoolean stop;

    Worker(LinkedBlockingDeque<Object> linkedBlockingDeque, Lock fillLock, AtomicBoolean stop) {

        this.linkedBlockingDeque = linkedBlockingDeque;
        this.fillLock = fillLock;
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (!stop.get()) {
                Object o = linkedBlockingDeque.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (o != null) {
                    handle(o);
                }
                if (linkedBlockingDeque.size() < 10) {
                    tryFill();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

    protected void tryFill() {

        if (fillLock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Filling");
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    linkedBlockingDeque.add(new Object());
                }

            } finally {
                fillLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void handle(Object object) {

        System.out.printf("object: %s\n", object);
        //TODO: blah blah blah stuff

    }

}
```

if you want other threads to block while the queue is filling, just have them wait on the lock in sequence if the fail to get it to fill.

e.g. change tryFill() to look like this:

protected void tryFill() {

```
if (fillLock.tryLock()) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Filling");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            linkedBlockingDeque.add(new Object());
        }

    } finally {
        fillLock.unlock();
    }
} else {
    fillLock.lock();
    try {

    } finally {
        fillLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

}

Alternately, you could use a Condition for this -- I'll leave that as an exercise to OP.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Unfortunately it does not anwser my question. I have a buch of consumer threads and one producer. Producer should wait until minimum threshold is reached, produce some objects, and then again wait. There's no need to use locks in order to restrict access to some object. If I could fill my pool from consumer thread it would be much easier, but again - it's not my case :)

Comment: The locks are not so much about restricting access as they are about not creating busy waits.  Can I ask you to rephrase your question?  Are you specifically asking for a lockless implementation (it's perfectly possible just requires a lot of fiddly atomics)?

Does the timing matter all that much?  You could do it in reverse -- just have the producer sleep for X seconds and every time it wakes up refill the queue to MAX_THRESHOLD instead of waiting to signal on MIN_THRESHOLD.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use another BlockingQueue to signal the Producer that it's time to wake up and fill the pool. Like this:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Main {

    public static final int LOWER_BOUND = 42;
    public static final int UPPER_BOUND = 84;
    public static final int CONSUMERS_COUNT = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue<Object> pool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        AtomicInteger currentPoolSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
        BlockingQueue<Object> commandsForProducer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(pool, currentPoolSize, commandsForProducer));
        producer.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMERS_COUNT; i++) {
            Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(pool, currentPoolSize, commandsForProducer));
            consumer.start();
        }
    }

}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Object> pool;
    private AtomicInteger currentPoolSize;
    private BlockingQueue<Object> commandsForProducer;

    Producer(BlockingQueue<Object> pool, AtomicInteger currentPoolSize, BlockingQueue<Object> commandsForProducer) {
        this.pool = pool;
        this.currentPoolSize = currentPoolSize;
        this.commandsForProducer = commandsForProducer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (currentPoolSize.get() < Main.UPPER_BOUND){
                pool.add(new Object());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " producer, items in pool:" +
                        currentPoolSize.incrementAndGet());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4); // Simulating work
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " producer is trying to sleep");
                    commandsForProducer.take();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " producer awakes");
                    commandsForProducer.clear();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Object> pool;
    private AtomicInteger currentPoolSize;
    private BlockingQueue<Object> commandsForProducer;

    Consumer(BlockingQueue<Object> pool, AtomicInteger currentPoolSize, BlockingQueue<Object> commandsForProducer) {
        this.pool = pool;
        this.currentPoolSize = currentPoolSize;
        this.commandsForProducer = commandsForProducer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (currentPoolSize.get() <= Main.LOWER_BOUND) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " signaled to producer");
                commandsForProducer.add(new Object());
            }
            try {
                pool.take();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consumer, items in pool:" +
                        currentPoolSize.decrementAndGet());
                Thread.sleep(50); // Simulating work
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```